# Rooted Android Background onTouchListener

Tags: android, background, root, ontouchlistener

I'm wonder if there is any way (on rooted phone) to use onTouch method from background, do some think and then dispatch this touch to foreground application.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? Do you want to optionally dispatch the touch event to the foreground application, essentially become a man in the middle? Or do you simply want to listen to the events?

Comment: I want to do something with my app when screen was touched but my application is in the bacground.

Answer (score 1):

Create a process and throw this at it: `getevent`

Multiple new lines will come in every time the screen is touched. Must have root since it contains sensitive touch position information.

Something like this:

```
try {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su getevent"); //su to get root access
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

  String line = "";
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        //A new line came in. So a touch event came in.
  }
} 
catch (IOException e) {}
```

Note: I haven't tested it but it should work. Maybe minor tweaks are necessary.

Comment: `getevent` could be a solution as root on Android does only apply to helper processes, not apps themselves.  However, `adb` is not applicable from on the device itself, only when using a PC to ask the device to do things.

Comment: You're right about the `adb shell`. I haven't had enough coffee today. I will edit my answer. On a side note, you can use `adb` to connect from one device to another. It's actually pretty useful to see logs on one tablet, the app on the other, and eclipse on the PC.

Comment: could you specify your answer ? I don't fully understand it.